# How to make diffrent class share their properties and methods with each other

Tags: javascript, class, oop

like this =>

```
StoragePoint = {}

class allCanShareWithMe {

  giveItHere() {
    saveToStoragePoint() {

    }
  }

  TakeItBack() {

  }
}

class iHaveSomeThingToShare {
  this.something = "popcorn";
  sendTo(allCanShareWithMe) {

  }

  acessFrom(allCanShareWithMe) {

  }
}
```

I Was Trying to Make All Properties in Class and every Methods Or any Other thing To be accessible in Another Class Or in A function Or Object Outside

Comment: There are a lot of problems in your code, for example the method `saveToStoragePoint` should not be inside anohter method. And `sendTo(allCanShareWithMe)` seems not valid because you use a class name, you probably mean to use an instance here? And what should it do? When is it called? Please clarify what you think should happen.

Comment: Sir , Yes , I have not done much practice with classess.I Was Trying To Create Objects That Share their Properties With each , Like Diffrent Elements on an html page have styles data like position . So I have Some Events Like Collisions between Objects That Can not be Done Without it .Right Now I Have Got  Model Working By Not Using The Javascript  Classes  .